# What $P(A, B)$ means?

Tags: probability, notation

I see this notation in some books $P(A, B)$ is this the same as $P(A \cup B)$ or $P(A \cap B)$?

As per context, I want to do an exercise.
Prove that $P(A|A, B) = 1$

Comment: $P(A,B)=_{\text{def}}P(A \cap B)$ ... $P(A\mid A,B)=\frac{P(A\cap A\cap B)}{P(A\cap B)}=\frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(A\cap B)}=1.$

Comment: @zoli What does the *def* part mean? Does it mean, *by definition*?

Comment: $P(A, B)$ is the same as $P(A \cap B)$. The $,$ should be read as AND.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition you have $P(A|B)=\frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)}$.

So, $P(A|A,B)=\frac{P(A \cap (A \cap B))}{P(A \cap B)}=\frac{P((A \cap A )\cap B)}{P(A \cap B)}=\frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(A \cap B)}=1$

Comment: I think would be more helpful if you explicitly stated what $P(A,B)$ means rather than doing the exercise, since the question is about the notation, not how to do the exercise.

Comment: Thanks, I figured the exercise would work easily if the notation meant intersection :D. And I just wanted to check. Thanks